# Amp-form does not redirect to another page

Tags: forms, redirect, amp-html

I have one input bar which must redirect to another https page (contains google-search) on submit. The code of the form is the next:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left hide-inputs buscadoMovilLine" role="search" target="_blank" action-xhr="https://www.tuotromedico.com/buscadorg.php" action="https://www.tuotromedico.com/buscadorg.php" method="get">
                <div class="form-group buscador">
                  <input class="SearchInputMovil2 inl" type="text" placeholder="Buscar..." class="form-control" name="q">
                  <button class="inl" type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search lupaBuscarMovilBoton2" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </div>  
        </form>
```

I have added the amp-form extension too. The official documentation says this:

> Redirecting after a submission
>   amp-form also allows publishers to redirect users to a new page after a submission happens through AMP-Redirect-To response header.
>
> Note that you'd also have to update your Access-Control-Expose-Headers
>   response header to include AMP-Redirect-To to the list of allowed
>   headers.
>
> The redirect URL must be absolute HTTPS URL otherwise AMP will throw
>   an error and redirection won't happen.

https://www.ampproject.org/es/docs/reference/components/dynamic/amp-form

But im not sure how have i to specify that.

Comment: Make sure your form has `target="_top"`

Answer (score 7):

I know 2 ways, this is for node:

```js
app.post('/register', function (req, res) {
    let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields) {
    
    res.setHeader('AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin', 'https://example.com/');
    
      if (fields.first_name && fields.last_name) {
        res.setHeader('AMP-Redirect-To', 'https://example.com/some-key');    
        res.status(200).json(fields);
      } else {
        res.status(400).json({error: 'Please select a size.'});
      }
});
```

and the second, in amp you can use navigateTo()

```html
        <form class="proceed__form" method="post" id="requirements-form"
              action-xhr="https://localhost:4040/check-requirements"
              target="_top"
              on="submit-success:AMP.navigateTo(url='https://google.com')"
        >
        </form>
        
        OR you can get variable from response 
        (res.status(200).json({message: 'success',  navigateTo: domain + '/profile'});)
        
        <form class="proceed__form" method="post" id="requirements-form"
              action-xhr="https://localhost:4040/check-requirements"
              target="_top"
              on="submit-success:AMP.navigateTo(url=event.response.navigateTo)"
        >
        </form>
```